# How to install Lumia Denim with Developer Preview?

Tags: update, lumia-denim-update

My Nokia Lumia 930 got Developer Preview enabled. Lumia Denim is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/) for my phone but my phone can't find the update. (I live in Sweden)

How do I update my DP phone to Lumia Denim?

Answer (score 9):

So, after some research, the short answer is: you will get the Denim update when it's available for your device. Being on the Developer Preview programme does not delay or prevent the update.

But if you're running a Dev Preview version of the OS, you may have Denim already but not know it!

**Causes of confusion**

1. The previous update, Cyan, was delayed for Dev Preview users because a bug was found when BitLocker was in use. This was eventually fixed and the firmware update was allowed for Dev Preview users.
2. There have been various reports of people getting the update only after unchecking the option in the [Preview for Developers app](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96), which is unusual as opting out of the Dev Preview programme doesn't downgrade the OS of the device.

**What actually happens**

Regardless of whether you're on the Dev Preview version or not, updates (OS and firmware) will install normally via **Settings** > **Phone Update**.

To confirm, look in **Settings** > **Extra+Info**...

- If you're **NOT** enrolled in the Dev Preview programme, the version will be correct
- But if you are enrolled, the version will be incorrect. Cyan will be listed instead of Denim.

If you go into Preview for Developers app, uncheck the option to remove your device from the Dev Preview programme, then check **Settings** > **Extras+Info** again - the correct version should be reported.

This is a bug with the **Extras+Info** app, not with the update process itself.

**How to confirm this yourself**

I used to following method to confirm the above...

1. Download the [Lumia Software Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987).
2. Restore your device back to 8.0 or 8.1. My Lumia 720 and 920 were reset back to 8.1.
3. After the initial setup, download the Preview for Developers app and install all updates - it can take 3 or 4 reboots to get all updates.
4. Check the firmware version reported in **Settings** > **About**, if Denim is installed it will match the expected versions for Denim. **Settings** > **Extras+Info** will incorrectly report Cyan.
5. Opt out of the Dev Preview programme (uncheck the option in the app) then check **Settings** > **Extras+Info** again and notice it now says Denim.
6. Opting back into the Dev Programme (check the option in the app) will make **Extras+Info** report Cyan again.

**Lumia/Nokia Camera issue**

If you update to Denim while on Dev Preview, Nokia Camera is not updated to Lumia Camera. It is also not possible to find or download the app from the Windows Phone Store. The only fix so far is to reset your phone.

Comment: How do you explain the update being installed after turning Dev Preview off? The update wasn't found when Dev Preview was on?

Comment: Coincidence or maybe a bug, but I haven't observed that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

1. **Disable Preview for Developers**.
2. Check for updates.
3. Install the Lumia Denim update.
4. Re-enable Developer Preview.

You just have to uncheck it in the Preview for Developers app. No need to restart your phone or anything.

#### Why does this work?

The Lumia Denim update is being pushed out via the *default update servers*. The Dev Preview servers doesn't have the Lumia Denim update on them and therefor you have to tell your phone to use the default servers instead.

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ViSomGillarWP/permalink/1577286749150150/).

Comment: That doesn't sound correct! If your device is running a Dev Preview build, turning off that option does nothing to the version of the software running on the phone. Denim should arrive for devices on the Dev Preview programme, Cyan was withheld for a while due to issues.

Comment: No, Denim is not being pushed out through the Dev Preview servers. You need to use the default update server to get the Denim update.

Comment: That's not correct. OS and firmware updates are two different checks. I'm waiting on a reply back from Microsoft, as their public blog post isn't specific about Denim

Comment: I can confirm, @MikaelDúiBolinder, worked exactly as you wrote. Didn't find 8.10.14226.359 until I disabled Dev Preview. I was on 8.10.14219.341 before the update.